# Aggregate by max of another field

Tags: django, django-models

Hey I have a model named `Visit`. With fields `date`, `person`, `id`. I want to get all persons who do not have visits in last three months. Can you help me, please?

What I have so far. Results are not what I wanted to see.

```
visits_anotated = Visit \
    .objects \
    .only('id', 'date', 'person') \
    .values('id', 'date', 'person') \
    .annotate(latest_visit=Max('date')) \
    .filter(latest_visit__lte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=14))
```

Comment: `person` is a `ForeignKey`? To what model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hey. Sorry for late response. It's not a FK. It's a CharField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need to do an aggregate for this. You should be able to filter to people who have visited in the past three months, then find all the other persons.

```
three_months_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=14)
recent_people = Visit.objects.filter(
    date__gte=three_months_ago
).values('person').distinct()
earlier_people = Visit.objects.exclude(
    person__in=recent_people
).values('person').distinct()
```

If person were a foreign key, you could do:

```
Person.objects.exclude(visit_set__date__gte=three_months_ago).distinct()
```